# How can I transition between two nuxt pages, while first waiting on a child component transition/animation to finish?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, nuxt.js

I have a question regarding transitions. When transitioning from one page to the other, is it possible to wait for a child transition/animation (extra file, extra component) to finish and then transition to the next page?

Example:

1) Home (Page Component)

a) Logo (Vue Component)

2) About (Page Component)

When I click on the About one the homepage, I first would like to animate the Logo component, then fade out the whole homepage and then route to the About page.

Here the relevant code:

**Index.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home" style="opacity: 0">
    <Logo v-show="showChild"/>
    <nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
    <p>Homepage</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from "~/components/Logo.vue";
import { TweenMax, CSSPlugin } from "gsap";

export default {
  components: {
    Logo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: true
    };
  },
  transition: {
    enter(el, done) {
      console.log("Enter Parent Home");
      this.showChild = true;
      TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
        opacity: 1,
        onComplete: done
      });
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      this.showChild = false;
      TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: done
      });
      console.log("Leave Parent Home");
      console.log("Child Visible: " + this.showChild);
    },
    appear: true,
    css: false
  }
};
</script>
```

**Logo.vue**

```
<template>
  <transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave" mode="out-in" :css="false">
    <div style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      <img
        style="objec-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%"
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80"
      >
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    showChild: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    enter(el, done) {
      console.log("Enter Child Home");
      TweenLite.fromTo(el, 1, { x: -100 }, { x: 0, onComplete: done });
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      console.log("Leave Child Home");
      TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
        x: -100,
        onComplete: done
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**About.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="about" style="opacity: 0">
    <nuxt-link to="/">Home</nuxt-link>
    <p>About</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  transition: {
    enter(el, done) {
      console.log("Enter Parent About");
      TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
        opacity: 1,
        onComplete: done
      });
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      console.log("Leave Parent About");
      TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: done
      });
    },
    appear: true,
    css: false
  }
};
</script>
```

I have also created a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-psks0

Unfortunately I am stuck with two problems:

1) The leave transition of the child component (Logo) isn't starting right now.

2) I would like to first finish the Child Component (Logo) transition and then finish the home page transition and then route to the about page. Is that even possible?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards
Chris

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please copy the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Okay thanks. Have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing i would wrap your custom transition in your home.vue file something like this:

```
<transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave" mode="out-in" :css="false">
   <client-only>
      <Logo v-if="showChild"/>
   </client-only>
</transition>


export default {
   data() {
      return {
         showChild: true
      };
   },
   methods: {
      enter(el, done) {
         console.log("Enter Child Home");
         TweenLite.fromTo(el, 1, { x: -100 }, { x: 0, onComplete: done });
      },
      leave(el, done) {
         console.log("Leave Child Home");
         TweenLite.to(el, 1, {
         x: -100,
         onComplete: this.$router.push("/about")
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And the idea here is that you use instead of an `nuxt-link` an common `a` tag or `button` that just set your `showChild` to false, that will trigger your leave method.

```
<button @click="showChild = false" />
```

And at the end of your leave method you set `this.$router.push("/about")` when your transition is finished. In theorie your logo should transition first, and when its finished your page transition should start at the end then.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tipp with just delaying the start of the route to the onComplete function. I optimized it a bit more by emiting from the child back to the parent. So I can have the start of the route in the parent component. Here is a updated Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-ex24q

Comment: i am glad that i could help you